# require path for plugins in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a plugin in here:

*myproject\vendor\plugins\myplugin*

How can i activate this plugin? what should i write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't think you need to `require` anything.

**EDIT**: As @Ryan Bigg said, if your plugin has either a `init.rb` or `plugin_name.rb` file, it will be automatically loaded. This goes without saying that you should `require` your plugin's files from within that file.

Comment: This is correct, but a little bit more expansion is required: provided you have _vendor/plugins/plugin_name/init.rb_ or _vendor/plugins/plugin_name/lib/plugin_name.rb it will be automatically loaded.